# Why is a CSS Variable struck out in Chrome Debugger?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug an issue where a couple of my CSS Variables are being overridden by something else. However, I don't know what is overriding them. For standard CSS properties (like `font-family`), it is easy to figure this out in the "Computed" tab, but how do I figure this out for CSS Variables? They don't show in the Computed tab.

[image]

Comment: CSS variables, really ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They don't show in the Computed tab.

They do if you check “Show all”.